# Inner typedef changes depending on parent class

Tags: c++, templates, using

I give up, please help explain this behaviour. The example I present below is the simplest one I could think of, but it sums up the problem (using g++ 4.9.2 on Cygwin with c++14 enabled). I want to create a class which will behave similar to `std::mem_fn`. Here is my class:

```
template <class R, class T, R(T::*P)() const >
struct property {

    static R get(const T& t) {
        return (t.*P)();
    }
};
```

where `R` is the return type and `T` is the type of the object I am interesting in. The third template parameter is a pointer to member function. So far, so good.

I then create a simple class which holds an integer as follows

```
class data_class {

public:

    unsigned get_data() const {
        return m_data;
    }

private:
    unsigned m_data;
};
```

This is the class which will be used in the `property` class shown before.

Now I create two classes which inherit from `data_class` as follows

```
struct my_classA
: public data_class {

    using data = property<unsigned, data_class, &data_class::get_data>;
};

//same as my_classA, only templated
template <int I>
struct my_classB
: public data_class {

    using data = property<unsigned, data_class, &data_class::get_data>;
};
```

They have the exact same inner typedef, but `my_classB` is templated. Now the following types should in theory be the same:

```
using target_t = property<unsigned, data_class, &data_class::get_data>;
using test1_t = typename my_classA::data;
using test2_t = typename my_classB<1>::data;
```

However my compiler says that only `test1_t` and `target_t` are the same. The type deduced for `test2_t` is apparently

```
property<unsigned int, data_class, (& data_class::get_data)> >
```

where this type has these brackets around the pointer to member function. Why `test2_t` is not the same as `target_t`? Here is the full code in case you want to try it on your system. Any help is much appreciated.

```
#include <type_traits>

class data_class {

public:

    unsigned get_data() const {
        return m_data;
    }

private:
    unsigned m_data;
};

//takes return type, class type, and a pointer to member function
//the get function takes an object as argument and uses the above pointer to call the member function
template <class R, class T, R(T::*P)() const >
struct property {

    static R get(const T& t) {
        return (t.*P)();
    }
};

struct my_classA
: public data_class {

    using data = property<unsigned, data_class, &data_class::get_data>;
};

//same as my_classA, only templated
template <int I>
struct my_classB
: public data_class {

    using data = property<unsigned, data_class, &data_class::get_data>;
};

//used to produce informative errors
template <class T>
struct what_is;

//all 3 types below should, in theory, be the same
//but g++ says that test2_t is different
using target_t = property<unsigned, data_class, &data_class::get_data>;
using test1_t = typename my_classA::data;
using test2_t = typename my_classB<1>::data;

static_assert(std::is_same<target_t, test1_t>::value, ""); //this passes
static_assert(std::is_same<target_t, test2_t>::value, ""); //this does not

int main() {

    what_is<test1_t> t1;
    what_is<test2_t> t2;
}
```

Comment: Try actually using `test2_t` (like declaring a variable of that type) to get *very* confusing messages: "error: ‘& data_class::get_data’ is not a valid template argument for type ‘unsigned int (data_class::*)() const’", "error: it must be a pointer-to-member of the form ‘&X::Y'".

Comment: Works in GCC <= 4.8 and in Clang. Appears to be a regression in 4.9+.

Comment: @T.C: Thanks for this. Can you provide a link to the bug report please? Also post it as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: Unrelated, but auto & decltype for the return type would simplify your design.

Comment: I don't know if this makes a difference but with your full code the way it is shown; when I paste it into Visual Studio 2013 I get compiler errors stating that "typename" can not be used outside a template declaration where you are declaring test1_t & test2_t, then the next two compiler errors state that t1 & t2 uses undefined struct what_is<test1_t> where both are trying to use test1_t.  The MS compiler errors are C2899 & C2079. I don't know if this will help or not, since you are using a different compiler.

Comment: (continued...)  Here are links about the compiler errors: https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(C2899);k(vs.output)&rd=true & https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(C2079);k(vs.output);k(%22test%2Fmy_classA%3A%3Adata%22);k(%22my_classA%3A%3Adata%22);k(using);k(DevLang-C%2B%2B);k(TargetOS-Windows)&rd=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code with c++11 because I'm not very familiar with c++14 yet. But all I replaced were the using (aliases) with typedefs and simplified the code a little bit. Nothing to affect its output.

I got the desired results by adding a typename T to the inherited classB template which when instantiated, it will replace the R with T, so in this case "unsigned".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename R, typename T, R(T::*P)() const>
struct property
{
    static R get(const T& t)
    {
        return (t.*P)();
    }
};


struct data_class
{
    private:
        unsigned m_data;

    public:
        unsigned get_data() const
        {
            return m_data;
        }
};

struct my_classA : public data_class
{
    typedef property<unsigned, data_class, &data_class::get_data> data;
};

template <typename T, int>
struct my_classB : public data_class
{
    typedef property<T, data_class, &data_class::get_data> data;
};


int main()
{

    typedef typename my_classA::data normClassA;
    typedef typename my_classB<unsigned,1>::data tmplClassB;

    std::cout<< std::is_same< property<unsigned, data_class, &data_class::get_data> , normClassA >::value <<std::endl;
    std::cout<< std::is_same< property<unsigned, data_class, &data_class::get_data> , tmplClassB >::value <<std::endl;

}
```

The result is this:

```
~$g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
~$./a.out 
1
1
```

I think the problem has to do with the class template instantiation criteria because when I originally tried to print the sizeof's of the two classes, my_classA::data returned 1, but my_classB<1>::data ended in a compiller error. I'm still quite fuzzy as to why this occurs. Technically it should have instantiated the class template just fine. Maybe it's the property inside the classB template that was falsely instantiated. I'll look more into this but if you find the answer, please post it. It's an interesting one!

EDIT:
The original code works fine on Cygwin GCC 4.8.2. Result is 1 and 1. Maybe it's just a gcc4.9.2 compiler issue.